# Basic CSS debugging in Internet Explorer 8 using compatibility mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, doctype, ie8-compatibility-mode

Okay, I'm not doing anything fancy here, but it's driving me crazy that I can't get it to work.

I'm having trouble with the button formatting on a form, but only in Internet Explorer 7.

I have a simple form:

```
<div id="menusearch">
     <form id="searchform" method="get" action="process.php">
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s_name" class="input_text"  />
            <input type="submit" class="button submit" accesskey="s" value="" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The CSS for the button is as follows:

```
#menusearch .button {
    margin: 0;
    width:97px;
    height:30px;
    background-image: url('images/search.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;
    border: none;
}
```

The background image is just a simple button image, but in Internet Explorer 7 it's just showing a standard default button without the image. It works in every other browser I've tried it in. Help would be appreciated.

Now, I'm using Internet Explorer 8 (compatibility mode) and the developer tools to check it out and see what's going wrong and I've noticed something weird. For certain lines of CSS, it seems to be ignoring them. So in the above for example, the developer tool shows as follows:

```
background-image: url(images/search.png); BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none
```

And it's showing this all as one line without the tick boxes, like it's not recognizing this as separate CSS rules. I can find other places in my CSS where I'm using background-image just fine and other places where I've set the borders as well. I've copied and pasted over the CSS code and still get the same errors.

What am I doing wrong?

***EDIT***

Okay, I've stripped it down and found that my problem is actually in my [Document Type Declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration),

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I remove it, and it works. So then, I need to change my original question to the following: What should my Document Type Declaration be?  I've never really understood the different ones and have always just used the same one...

so, the trimmed down source code as requested:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #menusearch .button {
                margin: 0;
                width:97px;
                height:30px;
                background-image: url('http://www.netbsd.org/images/download-icon-orange.png');
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-position:left top;
                border: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="hspace">
            <div id="mspace">
                <div id="menu">
                    <div id="menusearch">
                        <form id="searchform" method="get" action="process.php">
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s_name" class="input_text"  />
                                <input type="submit" class="button submit" accesskey="s" value="" />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I've left off the Document Type Declaration.

Comment: *I'm not certain*, but I think that's just IE's Developer Tools behaving in a spastic manner. I don't think it's relevant to your problem. If you could make an example page on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), I'll take a look.

Comment: cool. I was starting to worry that I was doing something wrong, especially since it was showing up right where my formatting problem was. I'm looking as JS Bin now. thanks!

Comment: okay, now I'm annoyed. I can't get it to reproduce in JS Bin. grrr.

Comment: Take your page which has the bug. Take out as much stuff as you can, while making sure that the problem still occurs. Post the code inside the file in your question.

Comment: Thnaks thirtydot. I'm being stupid and forgetting the basics of tearing it down to find the issue. Looks like it was the doc type that is playing up. updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: That doctype will trigger (Almost?) Standards Mode in IE. If you remove that doctype line entirely, you're in Quirks Mode. So apparently it works in Quirks Mode, but not Standards. At this point, it'd help massively to see your reduced test case page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix in this case is remarkably simple. Change your `border`, like this:

```
border: 0 solid #000
```

And it's fixed. Who knows why, IE7 is crazy.

You can keep your original doctype.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using `input type="image"` which can take an image src like this:

```
<input type="image" src="/path/to/image.png" value="Submit" />
```

The issue with this way, however, is that a rollover state would have to be done with JavaScript code. If you need more control over the button through CSS you could also use a <button> tag which Internet Explorer can style better than a standard `input type="submit"`.

Comment: I try to avoid using javascript where CSS can do the job such as with the rollovers. However, I've just found that i was asking the wrong question apparently. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it for my case,

1. Add the value `='Submit or whatever'`.
2. Add this CSS to the button,

   ```
       text-indent: -9999px
   ```